# gridview Devexpress c#

Tags: c#, devexpress

i use Devexpress 8.1 and i can't change font color of the gridview but i just want to change font color in the same row

```
Grup Adı    Kullanıcı Adı    Şifre

kitap       aykut            12345
**bilgi       kemal            67890**
defter      ayşe             15888
```

i mean I want to change the color of the text in bold

Comment: Are you saying you just want to change the color of a specific column or do you want to change the color of specific text within a column?

Comment: windows form application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following topic in our documentation:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758

It explains how to customize the XtraGrid's appearance.

Comment: Did you actually find how to change the font color? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the [`RowCellStyle` event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic).